# How to write unit test case for the given code

Tags: angular, testing

```
VacationFRP = [{key: 'test', value: '123456'}, {key: 'test1', value: '654321'}];
links = [{id: 'test', showTab: false}, {id: 'test1', showTab: false}];
VacationFRP.forEach(frp => {
    from(!!(frp.value)).subscribe(access => {
        const index = this.links.findIndex(item => {
            return item.id === frp.key;
        });
        this.links[index].showTab = access;
    });
});
```

I am facing issue to write unit test case for the above given code

Comment: Hi , can you give please provide the whole function. you can check if this.links has value as expected.  permHasEvery() is a function..?

Comment: permHasEvery checking have value or not

Comment: permHasEvery will return true or false;

Comment: you can spyon(component,'permHasEvery').and.returnValue("true");
you can expect function needs to prove what as your condition.
expect().toEqual()

Comment: permHasEvery is not important here we can remove it

Comment: if you don't want the inner function - you can call component.yourfunction() and expect ().toEqual() (the condition you want to test.)

Comment: unable to cover the  subscribe inner part here @monica

Comment: @monica any suggestion?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.